# Swimming to shore from the gulf stream in the middle of a hurricane

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

So, our favorite serial killer turns his boat into an oncoming hurricane and then apparently swims ashore. I have seen some reference to the gulf stream being 5-7 miles out from Palm Beach - which might even be an underestimate since we don't know exactly where he was. Doesn't it strain credulity that he could swim such a distance in the middle of a hurricane? People compete in such events (10 km swims or more - 6.2 miles), but we've never SEEN him swim - are we to believe he could really have done this?

Comment: Well you know, lumberjacks can swim long distances in hurricanes pretty well.

Comment: Wood doesn't sinks. He fount Atlantis full of woods in the hurricane which made him pick his new job as a lumberjack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In an interview with Executive Producer Scott Buck he explains that it is mentioned in a different episode that Dexter had an emergency life raft on the Slice of Life, implying that the raft is how Dexter got back to land. The full interview can be viewed on the [Hollywood Reporter website](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/dexter-series-finale-showrunner-scott-632536).

Answer (score 13):

Earlier in the season, Dexter was showing his boat to a prospective buyer.  He gave a rundown of the features of the boat, which included some sort of emergency life raft.  So he likely used that raft to escape once he'd put the boat in the path of the hurricane.